# Prove that $ex \leq e^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

This is easy to prove for negative $x$ but what about positive $x$? Should I use MVT?

Comment: You could note that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=e^x$ is convex, and that $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, g(x)=ex$ is tangent to $f$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Taylor series would work here...

Comment: It is better to replace $x$ by $x + 1$ to get $e^{x} \geq 1 + x$.

Answer (score 1):

You should prove that:

$$0 \leq e^{x-1}-x=f(x)$$

Let's calculate derivative of $f(x)=e^{x-1}-x$, it's:

$$f'(x)=e^{x-1}-1$$

Note that $f'(x)<0$ for $x<1$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x>1$. So $f(x)$ reaches the smallest value at $x=1$, but we can calculate that $f(1)=0$, so

$$f(x) \geq f(1)=0$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality is equivalent to $e^{x-1}\ge x$, which, after substitution $y:=x-1$ is equivalent to
$$e^y\ge 1+y.$$

You can find many proofs for this one:

- [Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex)
- [Prove that $e^x\ge x+1$ for all real $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252541/prove-that-ex-ge-x1-for-all-real-x?lq=1)
- [Proof of $e^x - 1 \geq x$ for ${x: -1 \leq x < 0}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784993/proof-of-ex-1-geq-x-for-x-1-leq-x-0?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$f(x):=ex-e^x\implies f'(x)=e-e^x=e(1-e^{x-1})=0\iff x=1$$

But also

$$f''(1)=-e^1<0$$

so that at $\;x=1\;$ we have a maximum point... End the argument now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the convexity of $\exp$ at the point 1 to get:
$$
\exp x \ge \exp' 1 \times (x - 1) + \exp 1  = ex
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note the tangent to $y=e^x$ at $x=1$ is
$$ y-e = e(x-1), $$
and the Taylor series for $e^x$ about $x=1$, with remainder, is
$$ e^x -ex = \int_1^{x} (x-t)e^{t} \, dt, $$
and the integrand is clearly positive for $x>1$. For $x<1$, you can rearrange integrand and limits to show the integral is still positive.