# Proof that $\exp(x)-1 > x^2 ,\forall x>0$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that

$\exp(x)-1 > x^2 ,\forall x>0$

What I've tried so far:

for $0<x<1$ I know that the equation is valid because:

$\exp(x)-1= x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ...$

so considering only the first term ($x$) I compared $x^2$ with it by subtracting both

$x^2-x = x(x-1)$

so for $0<x<1$ this is always positive.

Then I tried to compare the first four terms of $\exp(x)$ with $x^2$ by dividing it by $x^2$ trying to find where it is greater than one

$\exp(x)-1 > x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}$

$\frac{(x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!})}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{6} + \frac{x^2}{24}$

I ignored the first term $\frac{1}{x}$ because if the rest of the equation was already bigger than $1$ for $x>1$ then the problem would be solved.

Solving the equation:

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{6} + \frac{x^2}{24} > 1$ with $x>0$

$\frac{x^2}{24} + \frac{x}{6} - \frac{1}{2}> 0$ with $x>0$

Its roots are at $x=-6$ and $x=2$. So for $x>2$ the equation is also valid

I still do not know how to prove that $\exp(x)-1>x^2$ for $1<x<2$.

Edit: the solution from rogerl is much better than mine, but just for completeness using the comment from JetfiRex

considering the first two terms:

$x + \frac{x^2}{2!} > x^2$

$x - \frac{x^2}{2} > 0$

$x(1 - \frac{x}{2}) > 0$

x=0 and x=2 are solutions of this downward parabola, so the equation is also valid from 0 to 2

Comment: Hint: for $x$ in $(1,2)$, take one more term. That is, $x+x^2/2>x^2$

Comment: Alt. hint: let $\,f(x) = e^x-x^2-1\,$, then $\,f(0)=0\,$ and $\,f'(x)=e^x - 2x \gt 0\,$ on $\,\mathbb R^+\,$ because [$\,e^x \ge e \cdot x\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263454/prove-that-ex-leq-ex-for-all-x-in-mathbbr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} > x^2$ reduces to
$$\frac{1}{6}x(x^2-3x+6) > 0,$$
which is true for all $x>0$ since the discriminant of the quadratic is negative.